# saving matlab file (.mat) with dynamic name

Tags: matlab, dynamic, save

```
for m = 1:length(lst_region)
out=cellfun(@(x) str2double(x(1:strfind(x,'_')-1)),lst_region(m));
str=[num2str(out(1)) '.mat'];
save ( str ,distance);
end
```

> Error using save
>   Argument must contain a string. Line 3

I want to save files like '1.mat' '2.mat' etc.. but i have error can you please help me to fix it

Comment: Use `save(str, 'distance')`?

Comment: @RobertStettler thank you, it's the solution, can you explain me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `distance` is a variable in your workspace, you will have to call `save(str, 'distance');`. You have to enter the name of the variable, not the variable itself.